# Generating download.bit from commandline

Tags: fpga, xilinx, elf

We are trying to automate the whole process of building,programming FPGA and launching from Xilinx. Hence,I was programming the FPGA using iMPACT as mentioned in the [link](http://www.fpgadeveloper.com/2009/10/use-impact-to-download-bit-file.html), but iMPACT is not generating download.bit from system.bit.

From Xilinx I see that, along with the .bit and .bmm file, we can also assign an "ELF File to Initialize in Block RAM" and currently in the system I am using, it is set to "bootloop" for both the processors. What is this bootloop and where can I find it ? If I can find it, I think I can program the FPGA from the commandline using data2mem.exe. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your 2 bit files. iMPACT does not translate or merge bit files. Data2Mem can be use to overwrite or exchange BlockRAM data after P&R.

Answer (score 2):

The general form for automating impact downloading is:

```
setmode -bscan
setcable -p auto
identify
assignfile -p <index> -file <some-file>.bit
program -p <index>
quit
```

saved in a .cmd file with  and  replaced as necessary.  Then you would run impact in batch mode as

```
impact -batch <some-file>.cmd
```

Seems like for your case, you should put 'system.bit' in the cmd file so that impact will try to load from the correct file.

If this doesn't solve your issue, please add some more details to clarify.